# How can I replace an entire file name using a CSV index in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

When the .mp3 files are downloaded from the call recording website they are not in our desired format. I want to replace the entire filename and move the files into a new folder. The default format is:

```
incoming#_outgoing#_yyyymmdd_hhmmss
```

I have a Search and Replace CSV which uses data from the call recording website:

Replace: Telephone call reference (TelCall_yyyymmdd_Surname)

Search: Exact call time from call recording software (yyyymmdd_hhmmss)

I have written a script that searches for the exact time and date in the filename and replaces it with the desired format:

```
    $folder = "C:\Users\R\Desktop\ClientCallsTest"
    $csv = "C:\Users\R\Desktop\20180104-0224_Client_Calls_PS_CSV.csv"

    $keywords = @{}
    Import-Csv $csv | ForEach-Object {
      $keywords[$_.Search] = $_.Replace
    }

    Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
      $newname = $_.Name
      foreach ($word in $keywords.Keys) {
        $newname = $newname.Replace($word, $keywords[$word])
      }

      if ($_.Name -ne $newname) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname
      }
    }
```

It indeed does rename the file, but only replaces the string in the CSV table. My desired format is just TelCall_yyyymmdd_Surname.

How would I modify this code to replace the entire file name (deleting the incoming/outgoing numbers at the beginning), rather than just the string in the lookup table? I'm sure it's a quick change but I'm stumped.

Comment: You just want `$newname` to be `yyyymmdd_hhmmss`?

Comment: I want $newname to be TelCall_yyyymmdd_Surname, which is the replace item in the CSV table. The script is currently only replacing the 'Search' item, I want to delete the phone numbers at the beginning of the filenames too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string `Split()` function to split your original name into parts, like:

```
$nameParts = "incoming#_outgoing#_yyyymmdd_hhmmss" -split "_"
```

will give you an array like:

```
PS C:\>$nameParts
incoming#
outgoing#
yyyymmdd
hhmmss
```

you can then assemble your now string like:

```
$newName = "TelCal_" + $nameParts[2] + "_" + $surename
```

where `$surename` contains your data from the csv file

Comment: The script never features the original filenames as these are taken from the CSV table, so I would be unable to specify its parts.